# Reading HTTP request on an Adhoc network

Tags: http, networking, request, adhoc

I have an app on my iPhone that makes HTTP request to my home router to talk to a home automation router that my phone connects to via wifi.   How can I read the HTTP requests made from the iPhone if I make an adhoc network and send the request from the app that way?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, what you have is:

iPhone - (Internet) - Home Router - Automation Router - Phone

The easiest way to capture the HTTP request from the iPhone would be to connect any computer in place of the Automation Router with the Automation Router's IP address, and run wireshark on the computer to capture the incoming packets.

If you want to build an adhoc network, you would just need:

iPhone - Any Wifi capable Router/Switch - Computer

Then you will have to configure the app on the iPhone to send to the Computer's IP address, and again, you can run wireshark on the computer to capture the packets.

Hope this helps.